# Power BI - Percentage change from year on year based on avg sale price in row

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Im new to PowerBI and was wondering if someone could help me how to calculate a Year on year % change. I have made a measure for Total Sales in the year and Average sales Price. I would now like to calcualte the %change of the Avg sale price year on year.

Measures used:

AVG_SALE = AVERAGE([PRICE])

TOTAL_SALES = COUNT([CITY])

[image]

Comment: Could you describe the other measures that you've used? So we can help you in a better way

Comment: Hi Henrique, these are the only 2 measures ive used. CITY,TOWN,PRICE, YEAR(DATE) are all columns within my data just filtered down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following measure:

```
YoY = [AVG_SALE]/CALCULATE([AVG_SALE];SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('yourTable'[Year]))-1
```

If you want to treat the possible errors (maybe you miss some years in your data, or you've got no sales on specific year):

```
YoY = IFERROR([AVG_SALE]/CALCULATE([AVG_SALE];SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('tableName'[Year]))-1;BLANK())
```

Remember to replace `tableName` with the name of your table!

Comment: The measure doesnt seem to want to display in the visual? I get this error MdxScript(model)(26,29) Calculation error in measure '4'[YoY]: A column specified in the call to function 'SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR' is not of type DATE. this is not supported

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-do-I-tell-PowerBI-that-my-year-column-is-a-date-in-quot-YYYY/td-p/60459) to change the type of your Year column to date. Probably it has another type, maybe integer or text type. That´s why you are receiving the error message.